# How does Twitter do noscript redirect and what's the point?

Tags: javascript

Twitter has this within their  tags:

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; URL=/?_twitter_noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```

Body has this:

```
  <noscript>
    <div class="front-no-js-warn">
      <h3>Twitter.com makes heavy use of JavaScript</h3>
      <p>If you cannot enable it in your browser's preferences, you may have a better experience on our <a href="http://m.twitter.com">mobile site</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </noscript>
```

with CSS :

```
.front-no-js-warn{position:absolute;top:50px;
left:50%;
height:30px;
width:798px;
padding:15px 20px;
margin:0 0 0 -418px;
z-index:2;color:#ddd;
line-height:1.5;
background-color:#111;
background-color:rgba(20,20,20,.9);
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
}
.front-no-js-warn h3{color:#FEC632;font-weight:bold;}
.front-no-js-warn a{color:#75C6F7;}
```

So when you have javascript disabled, you see `div class="front-no-js-warn"`

My question is what is the point of redirecting to `?_twitter_noscript=1` and how do I implenent that? I tried doing similar and it endlessly tries to redirect.

Comment: You're probably redirecting to the same page? You'd need to redirect to one that doesn't include the redirect. The `?_twitter_noscript=1` is likely telling the server to modify the page or send a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for $_GET['_twitter_noscript=1'] (php) in your index page and if it is present display a different page.

Example:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['_twitter_noscript']) {
        echo "Display javascript-less page";
    } else {
        echo "noscript...meta refresh... etc etc ... /noscript";
        //Rest of the page...
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what the point of the redirect is if the no-javascript warning div is wrapped in a <noscript>.

Answer (score 1):

They do this so they can determine which users have JavaScript disabled and let them know that as a result of that they will not experience everything Twitter has to offer as a result.